# C++ Определение физического расположения файла на диске

Tags: c++, winapi, файловая-система

Для начала, мне не даётся использование DeviceIoControl.
Говорит, что hFile неверный, хотя он не NULL. С какими атрибутами открывать?

```
ANDLE hFile = CreateFile(path,
    GENERIC_READ,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    0,
    NULL);

RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER rpb;
STARTING_VCN_INPUT_BUFFER startingVcn;
DWORD dwBytesReturned;
OVERLAPPED overlapped;

DWORD dwFragments = 0, dwTotalClusters = 0;

    // ...

    DeviceIoControl(hFile, 
        FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT,
        &startingVcn, sizeof startingVcn,
        &rpb, sizeof rpb,
        &dwBytesReturned, &overlapped);

     // ... while(dwError == ERROR_MORE_DATA);
```

Далее алгоритм будет следующий:
Вызвать GetLastError и по коду ошибки определить дальнейшие действия.

1. Если это первая итерация и `ERROR_HANDLE_EOF`, значит файл резидентный, если не первая, то выход из цикла.
2. Если `NO_ERROR`, файл занимает 1 фрагмент кластеров (т.е. все по-порядку, а не в разброс по диску).
3. Если `ERROR_MORE_DATA`, есть ещё на диске фрагменты этого файла.

Таким образом, будем иметь список всех фрагментов файла на диске ввиде списка пар StartLCN-ClustersLength.

Так же, понятия не имею, что делать, если файл резидентный. Как вытащить его положение на диске?

Работать всё это должно под FAT, FAT32 и NTFS (с поддержкой SPARSE, COMPRESSED и ENCRYPTED файлов).

Нужно это положение для программы безопасного удаления данных, т.е. потом я полученные кластеры затру.

Comment: "Говорит, что hFile неверный" кто и где говорит?

Comment: Чтобы `FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT` не ругалась на `hFile`, добавьте в `CreateFile` к `dwDesiredAccess` флаг `FILE_READ_EA`, а `dwFlagsAndAttributes` должна быть `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT`.

Comment: @kff, это к сожалению не работает: `HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"C:\\1.txt",
  GENERIC_READ | FILE_READ_EA,
  0,
  NULL,
  OPEN_EXISTING,
  FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT,
  NULL);`

Comment: @kff, возможно, нужно как-то особо указывать путь? Через `\\.\C:` или `\C:` или `\??\C:`?

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, DeviceIoControl GetLastError = 6.

Comment: @D.Stark а хэндл валидный? Проверка после CreateFile есть?

Comment: @D.Stark Если не ошибаюсь, путь должен предваряться `\\?\ `, т.е. `L"\\\\?\\C:\\1.txt"`.

Comment: @kff, указал текой путь, но DeviceIoControl всё равно говорит о Error 6.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, да проверка есть, валидный.

Comment: @D.Stark А что возвращает сам `DeviceIoControl`? И ещё попробуйте запустить программу с правами администратора.

Comment: @kff, возвращает FALSE (0), а права админа ничего не дают...

Comment: Мб вообще заюзать NtFsControlFile?

Comment: Вообще, у меня есть рабочий исходник, только на c#.
Там файл так открывается:
`using (var file = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)) {`

Comment: Ха. Нет ничего проще...
http://pastebin.com/B4zdwmj5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(lpFilePath, 
    FILE_READ_EA, 
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, 
    NULL, 
    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT, 
    NULL);

if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    wcout << "Open file error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
    system("pause");
    return -1;
}

PSTARTING_VCN_INPUT_BUFFER startingVcn = new STARTING_VCN_INPUT_BUFFER();
PRETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER prpb = new RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER();

DWORD dwBytesReturned = 0;
DWORD dwExtentNumber = 0, dwTotalClusters = 0;
DWORD dwError;

do
{
    DeviceIoControl(hFile,
        FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS,
        startingVcn, sizeof *startingVcn,
        prpb, sizeof *prpb,
        &dwBytesReturned,
        NULL);

    dwError = GetLastError();

    switch (dwError)
    {
    case ERROR_HANDLE_EOF:

        if (dwExtentNumber == 0)
            cout << "MFT Table..." << endl;
        else
            wcout << endl << 
            "Total clusters: " << dwTotalClusters << endl << 
            "Fragments: " << dwExtentNumber << endl;

        break;
    case NO_ERROR:

        wcout << "Fragment 0:" << endl <<
            "\tStart LCN: " << prpb->Extents->Lcn.QuadPart << endl <<
            "\tClusters: " << prpb->Extents->NextVcn.QuadPart - prpb->StartingVcn.QuadPart << endl << endl;

        wcout <<
            "Total clusters: " << prpb->Extents->NextVcn.QuadPart - prpb->StartingVcn.QuadPart << endl <<
            "Fragments: " << dwExtentNumber;

        break;
    case ERROR_MORE_DATA:

        wcout << "Fragment " << dwExtentNumber << ":" << endl <<
            "\tStart LCN: " << prpb->Extents->Lcn.QuadPart << endl <<
            "\tClusters: " << prpb->Extents->NextVcn.QuadPart - prpb->StartingVcn.QuadPart << endl << endl;

        dwTotalClusters += prpb->Extents->NextVcn.QuadPart - prpb->StartingVcn.QuadPart;
        startingVcn->StartingVcn.QuadPart = prpb->Extents->NextVcn.QuadPart;

        break;
    default:

        wcout << "DeviceIoControl error: " << dwError << endl;
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    }

    dwExtentNumber++;

} while (dwError == ERROR_MORE_DATA);

CloseHandle(hFile);

system("pause");
return 0;
```